# WordPress admin not showing latest post

Tags: wordpress

The post is displaying on the site but not in the Admin > All Posts section. I have checked the post in the database and it is identical to other entries (post_type and post_status).

I'm only using Advanced Custom Fields and MailChimp plugins. I've tried disabling these but the issue still persists. The post count shows the correct amount but the latest post is missing from the list.

Comment: Verify everything including dates,do a column by column comparison with the latest post showing.

Comment: @Mihai: The dates look ok. How can I do a column comparison? Thanks.

Comment: Go in the db and order by date or by post_id,table is wp_posts

Comment: I was offsetting the posts by one on the news page as per this article - https://codex.wordpress.org/Making_Custom_Queries_using_Offset_and_Pagination. The query was also running on the admin > posts page (of course). So I excluded it from running from the admin section.